# rest api meaning in POST or PUT

Tags: rest, api, http, put, http-verbs

I have referenced stackexchange's RESTful APIs.

From this, I have one situation that makes me confused.

I have this API:

`/users/{user_id}/followings`

On this API,

`GET` means get the all follwing user lists of `user_id`. This is good.

But, when I want to add **one** follwing user(this is kind of adding following user like instagram or facebook), should I have to use above REST API with `PUT`?

I'm confused using `PUT` with above API. Because, as above API means **all** follwing lists of `user_id`, if I use this API to `PUT`, it means `put` the **all** follwing users to `user_id`, not **one** following users.

Is it just OK to use above API to add(using `put` method) **one** following user to `user_id`?

Comment: Use GET to get the data, POST to add new data, PUT to update data, DELETE to remove data

Comment: @bub yeah, I know that mechanism. But what I mean is `/users/{user_id}/followings` means **all**, not the only **one**. So my question is that 'is it ok to use this API to add **one** following user to `user_id`'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just `POST` a new user to `/users/{user_id}/followings`. I wouldn't `PUT` on a list - you can use a `PATCH add` if you want to go down that path - see [this link](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/).